# Unity procedural TileMap generation without creating gameobject per tile

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've been searching all over the internet to find a efficient way to create procedural tilemap without creating a gameobject per each tile. There is none, or simply i couldn't find it, because i really don't know how to make a search for it. All the TileMap tutorials i found are creating tiles by creating hunderds of gameobjects. Thus the hierarchy in Unity is expanding uncontrollably.

I'm pretty sure this is not the "right" way to do it. Especially after seeing the new Unity 2D tools that supports tilemaps. Unity made it so, you can create tiles in "one" gameobject, not for each tile.

How to do it in the right way?

Comment: You've cross posted this to two SE sites. Pick one.

Comment: If you use texture atlases then having many objects should not be such a big problem. Even if you have 10000 tiles it will still be one draw call. I think having a single gameobject might make debugging difficult and you will lose some of the power of the editor. I would say leave the efficiency for when it becomes a problem. It might never become a problem. Unless of course you just want to learn new techniques then Emilio has a good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the sole task of "creating an efficient tilemap", your best option is to create a `TileMap` component that manages a procedural mesh made up of a collection of independent quads with uvs mapped to a tile atlas. This way you will even draw your whole map in one drawcall.

You'd need to know a thing or two about how meshes work, and texturing. It's very simple, and if you don't know but are curious about it, [catlikecoding's tutos are a good starting point](http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/procedural-grid/). In the tuto each quad on the grid shares vertices, but for this you'd want independent quads, so as to texture them properly.

Comment: Thank you for your respond, i have learned and even managed to make some prototype about it. It works just as I wanted.
But i have stucked on animating the tiles. I have a solution in my mind but i am not sure if it's logical and efficient.
So i asked an another question about it here, if you may want to check it out link is here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963298/is-animating-a-tile-in-a-tilemap-quad-per-tile-mesh-by-changing-quads-uv-posit

Thanks for the help again ^^